# Swift 4.2 Type 'NSAttributedString.Key' has no member 'accessibilitySpeechPitch'

Tags: ios, swift, xcode10, uiaccessibility, swift4.2

I’m moving some code from Swift 4.0 to 4.2, and I’m having trouble using UIAccessibilitySpeechAttributePitch. In my Swift 4.0 file, I used:

`NSAttributedStringKey(rawValue: UIAccessibilitySpeechAttributePitch)`

Even in Swift 4.0, I couldn’t use it directly as `NSAttributedStringKey.accessibilitySpeechPitch`, for some reason, but I could get around that by initialising using the raw value. I don’t seem to be able to do that in Swift 4.2.

If I try

```
NSAttributedString.Key(rawValue: UIAccessibilitySpeechAttributePitch)
```

in Swift 4.2, I get

> Invalid initializer call with same type 'NSAttributedString.Key' as
>   parameter

so obviously `UIAccessibilitySpeechAttributePitch` is recognised as an `NSAttributedString.Key`. 
However, if I use it directly, I get:

> 'UIAccessibilitySpeechAttributePitch' has been renamed to
>   'NSAttributedString.Key.accessibilitySpeechPitch'

with the suggested fix

> Replace 'UIAccessibilitySpeechAttributePitch' with
>   'NSAttributedString.Key.accessibilitySpeechPitch'

So I click the ‘fix’ button to change it to `NSAttributedString.Key.accessibilitySpeechPitch`, and then I get

> Type 'NSAttributedString.Key' has no member 'accessibilitySpeechPitch'

If I command-click on `UIAccessibilitySpeechAttributePitch` without first changing it to `NSAttributedString.Key.accessibilitySpeechPitch`, I get to this declaration, in UIAccessibilityConstants in UIKit:

```
extension NSAttributedString.Key {
//other stuff
    @available(iOS 7.0, *)
    public static let accessibilitySpeechPitch: NSAttributedString.Key
//other stuff
}
```

So, it obviously exists, but, how can my code use it? Do I need to import something extra for the accessibility constants, in addition to UIKit?

Edit: My actual code (with just some variable names changed) is as follows:

```
static let someColour=#colorLiteral(red: 1, green: 0.5763723254, blue: 0, alpha: 0.5)
static let attributes=[
    NSAttributedString.Key.backgroundColor: someColour,
    NSAttributedString.Key.strokeWidth: -3.0,
    NSAttributedString.Key.accessibilitySpeechPitch: 1.3
    ]
    as [NSAttributedString.Key : Any]
```

I have tried clean building. I'm using Xcode Version 10.0 (10A255)

Comment: `NSAttributedString.Key.accessibilitySpeechPitch` works for me. Try to clean and build again.

Comment: Show your actual code, in context, where you try to use `NSAttributedString.Key.accessibilitySpeechPitch`. It works fine for me in Xcode 10/Swift 4.2.

Comment: I added my code. Cleaning and building didn't help. :/ I'm in Xcode 10.0 (10A255)

Comment: Your code causes no errors when put in a Swift playground.

Comment: How weird; it works in a playground for me too. Any idea what could be wrong with my project or Xcode setup to make it not work in the project? Or should I ask another question for that?

Comment: Try restarting Xcode. And make sure your project is setup to use Swift 4.2.

Comment: I may have just found the problem. I have some targets in the project that are set up to use Swift 4.0, and others that use 4.2, and the file with this line in it is (deliberately, because it's code I want to share) included in both. If I remove the file from the Swift 4.0 target, I don't get that error any more. But how come I don't have a similar problem from changing NSAttributedStringKey to NSAttributedString.Key for Swift 4.2 compatibility?

Comment: @Angela I suggest you redo your question around your last comment now that you've narrowed down the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Try to

improt UIKit

Becouse the accessibilitySpeechPitch exists in the `UIKit -> NSAttribute` file, you can see it in `extension NSAttributedString.Key`

It worked